# Any way to have iPhone microphone only active if sound level is above a certain threshold?

Tags: iphone

I'm not sure what the proper terminology is, but I've used online gaming apps years ago where sound through microphone can be set such that it doesn't go through unless it's above a certain noise threshold.

Is this possible to do with calling from an iPhone? This would be really useful if you're calling in a noisy area because all the background noise would be filtered out .

I have an iPhone 11.

Answer (score -1):

You're describing VOX (Voice Activated Transmit), which iOS does not have as a feature.

Unfortunately there's no way to get this ability for calls.

Comment: VOX is not “voice operated transmit;” it’s *voice operated exchange* or *voice operated switch.*. Microphone gain is not the same as VOX.

Comment: VOX is widely used to define a variety of similar concepts like Voice Operated Transmission, Voice Activated Transmission, Voice Operated Transmit, Voice Activated Transmit, Voice Activated Switch, and Voice Operated Switch.

[NASA's Apollo glossary](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/apollo.glossary.html) defines it as:

`VOX: Voice Activated Transmission`

Comment: Since we're dealing with Telecom, how about we stick with what's generally accepted definition:  https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/V/vox.html. NASA doesn't use cell phones to talk to their astronauts.  It also doesn't address the issue re:  microphone gain.

Comment: Seems incredibly pedantic to look at a widely used term like VOX, which has broad and clear understanding to mean transmitting when voice activated, and to then narrowly define that term to only a particular case which doesn't apply to the current question, when the broader definition, certainly DOES apply to the current question. More importantly, I can't see the reason for that extreme pedantry. What possible help could collapsing VOX to *just* your defined context have for this question? Honestly don't think your comment is at all helpful. I can't see what your comment contributes at all.